# How do I Print data/Text extracted from PDF using python to a thermal or virtual Printer?

Tags: python, printing, thermal-printer, barcode-printing

I have managed to write a simple algorithm to fetch and text on a PDF using python. I  would love to print the output to a thermal/virtual printer. How do I do it ?

I have tried using win32print library . I want to print the output to a printer.

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77953752/how-do-i-fetch-and-print-only-the-table-in-a-pdf-despite-the-pdf-format-using-py